# When is One Polynomial "Similar" to Another

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions. We will say they are similar (in somewhat of an extension to what it means for linear maps to be similar) if there exists a bijection $p$ such that
$$f=p^{-1}\circ g\circ p.$$
Let this relation be denoted as $\sim$. Under what conditions can polynomials be similar? Specifically, I am trying to find out for which polynomials $f$ can we say that $f\sim T_n$ for some $n$ where $T_n$ is the $n$-th Chebyshev polynomial.
Note that when $f$, $g$, and $p$ are all restricted to linear functions from $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ this aligns with the normal definition of similar matrices. Could a similar equivalence be drawn for polynomial functions? Possibly one could consider matrices over the field $\mathbb{R}[x]$, and apply a similar theory to get partial results for the above problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** In the particular case where we are looking at the Chebyshev polynomials, by definition $T_n(\cos x)=\cos(nx)$. Hence with $c:[0,\pi)\to[-1,1),x\mapsto\cos x$ and $m:[0,\pi)\to[0,\pi)$, $x\mapsto nx$ mod $\pi$, we have $T_n\circ c=c\circ m$, i.e. $T_n=c\circ m\circ c^{-1}$. Therefore $T_n\sim m$, which is a linear map. Now $f\sim T_n$ iff it is similar to the linear map $x\mapsto nx$.

---

In general: let's exclusively discuss the case where $\phi$ is affine. If $f(x)=\sum a_ix^i$, then taking $\phi$ to be a translation $x\mapsto x-k$, then we have $\phi^{-1}\circ f\circ\phi$ to be $f(x-k)+k=\sum a_i(x-k)^i+k$. Hence, starting from any polynomial $f$, shifting its graph along the diagonal will always result in a similar function. Furthermore, the choice $\phi:x\mapsto kx$ will result in the similar function $f(kx)/k$, so we conclude that "shrinking" the graph of $f$ in a ratio-preserving manner will also result in the graph of a similar function.

Any polynomial of odd degree crosses the diagonal $y=x$ at least once, so bring this point to the origin (obtaining a similar function). By suitable scaling, we conclude that any odd degree polynomial $p(x)$ is similar to $xq(x)$, where $\partial q\leq\partial p-1$ ($\partial$ denotes the degree). Furthermore, it's not hard to show that similar functions must cross the diagonal the same number of times. This gives us several methods to prove that $f\nsim g$ by an affine bijection $\phi$:

1. If the number of roots of $f(x)-x$ is not the same as the number of roots of $g(x)-x$, then they are not similar;
2. For all the roots $x_k$ of $g(x)-x$, look at the similar monic polynomials $g'_k(x)=xh_k(x)$ defined by "bringing the root to the origin" and scaling such that the leading coefficient is $1$. Do the same for $f$. If the resulting monic polynomials are not all the same, then they are not similar.

I believe these are exhaustive; i.e. if $f$ passes both of these tests, then $f\sim g$ with affine $\phi$. I am however unable to prove this. If this is true, then it gives us a test for conclusively saying $f\sim g$ in the general case.

Comment: For polynomials that cross $y=x$ the list is exhaustive because $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. Hence by 2 if they are similar to the same thing then they are themselves similar. I don’t know about for polynomials that don’t cross $y=x$ however.

Comment: @WillFisher You're right! But don't all Chebyshev polynomials $T_n$, $n\geq 2$ cross $y=x$ at least once?

Comment: @WillFisher Actually, I think $T_n\sim nx$. Check the edit.

Comment: For the Chebyshev case I think you have to be careful. Because if $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Y$ then we are required to have $p:Y\to X$. The fact that $T_n\sim nx\mod \pi$ follows when you consider the functions on restricted domains and ranges, but I don't know if the result when considering them as functions on $\mathbb{R}$ follows.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you have $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Y$ and restrict the ranges to get $f^*:X\to f(X)\cup g(X)$ and $g^*:X\to f(X)\cup g(X)$ then $f^*\sim g^*\Leftrightarrow f\sim g$, but I think restricting domains would require additional hypotheses to get a similar implication.

Comment: @WillFisher If we know the values of all points of a polynomial $f$ on an interval $[a,b]$ ($b>a$), then we know $f$ on the whole real line, so every restriction of a polynomial onto an interval has a unique extension back into the full polynomial. I forgot the name of this theorem, but doesn't this guarantee what we need?